# VWO Split URL test no redirect link

Tags: ab-testing, vwo

I'm using VWO to do some split url testing. Is there some query param you can pass in the url so it doesn't get put into the a/b test and doesn't get redirected.

For example lets say I'm running a split URL test on

**mywebsite.com/a** vs. **mywebsite.com/b**

I want to give someone a link to **mywebsite.com/a** without being included in the split URL test, ensuring that they actually get to **mywebsite.com/a** and not **mywebsite.com/b**

Is there some query param or some other way I can ensure this?

(example: mywebsite.com/a?vwo_testing=false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my use case I was able to go to https://vwo.com/opt-out/ and opt out of being redirected. Another option is to add ?vwo_opt_out=1 param to the url.

Comment: Using this approach, the user gets opted out of the VWO tracking completely. Therefore, the same user won't be able to participate in any of the tests that you create going forward. I hope that's fine with you.

Comment: Yes, Eshan thank you for those details. In my specific case this is fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude someone from the test by using a Query Parameter segmentation to exclude the query parameter. You can refer to the article below to create a Custom Visitor Segment for this.

https://vwo.com/knowledge/how-to-define-custom-visitor-segments/

Segmentation would look like -
Query Parameter: vwo_testing IS NOT EQUAL TO false

You can reach out to support@vwo.com in case you have any further query.

Comment: Wouldn't help me in my case because I don't want have to define a custom visitor segment for every test I run.